# UDF Table UDV or Scalar UDF?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, user-defined-functions

I will do my best to make this question better than my last fiasco. I am getting the dreaded >"cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.PriMonthAvgPrice", or the name is ambiguous.<

I am attempting to find the avg sales price from the previous month. Here is my UDF:

```
USE [WoodProduction]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PriMonthAvgPrice]
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@endofmonth     datetime,
@begofmonth     datetime,
@PlantCode      varchar
)
RETURNS decimal (10,2)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @MonthEndAvgPrice  decimal (10,2)

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
SELECT @MonthEndAvgPrice =

(
    select  

        sum(Actual_Sales_Dollars/Actual_Volume)

        FROM

        woodproduction.dbo.plywood_layup_sales pls
        WHERE

        Production_Date between @begofmonth and @endofmonth
        and actual_volume <> 0
        and @PlantCode = pls.Plant_Code


)

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @MonthEndAvgPrice

END
```

This is my SELECT statement from my query:

```
    SELECT
DISTINCT    
    P.[Plant_Number]
    ,p.plant_name   
,pls.plant_code
    ,(pls.[Budget_Realization]) AS 'BR'
    ,(pls.[Actual_Volume] ) AS 'AV'
    ,(pls.[Budget_Volume])  AS 'BV'
--,sum (dpb.[Gross_Production_Per_Hr]) AS 'GPB'
    ,(p.Production_Volume) AS 'PV'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN    coalesce (pls.[Actual_Volume],0) = 0 and
                coalesce (pls.[Actual_Sales_Dollars],0) = 0
                THEN 0
        ELSE (pls.[Actual_Sales_Dollars]/pls.[Actual_Volume])
    END
    AS 'AP'
    ,pls.production_date
  ,[dbo].[PriMonthAvgPrice](@endofmonth,@begofmonth, pls.plant_code) AS 'PriMoAvgPrice'
```

My BASIC understanding is that I HAVE created a Scalar Function. From what I've been reading about my error however, This error returns on TVF's. Is this true? I created a SVF prior to this dealing with just determining a prior month end date so it wasn't as involved as this one where I create the query in the UDF.

Do I need to change this to a TVF? And if so, how do I incorporate SELECT * when I have to join multiple tables along with this?

Thanks in advance.

Aaron

Comment: Is there a `FROM` clause there too?

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious since I see a table reference qualified with a database name (`woodproduction.dbo.plywood_layup_sales`) in your function. Are you running this query in the same database where the function is created?

Comment: pls.[Actual_Sales_Dollars]/pls.[Actual_Volume])  = beware of integer math here if both your columns are integers. Also, I usually put ina a divide by zero check in any divsion, so that it won't brak if the bottom figure is 0 or null. You know you data and maybe it's not needed but it's a good habit to get into. Lots of times I have had an unexpected zero.

Comment: SELECT * should not be used in production code especially when there are joins. It is inefficient and causes the database to send more information across the newtork than is needed (the join fields are duplicated).

Comment: @HLGEM I figured as much and there are a LOT of joins throughout the whole query. I did a basic UDF for another dataset in this report but it didn't involve using a query like this. It was just a DATE UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the from clause, but is the database you created the function in part of it?

Does it work if you fully qualify the name (include the database)?

Have you independently tested the function with:

```
select [dbo].[PriMonthAvgPrice] ('01/01/2011', '02/01/2011', 'test')
```

Note: of course you would use some actual values that should return a result.

Please run this and tell us the values returned:

```
 SELECT Actual_Sales_Dollars,Actual_Volume, pls.PLant_code          
 FROM   woodproduction.dbo.plywood_layup_sales pls         
 WHERE  Production_Date between '09-01-2011'  and  '09-30-2011'          
        and actual_volume <> 0
```

Comment: Sorry @JNK. I knew I would miss something.  
  `FROM woodproduction.dbo.plywood_layup_sales pls

    inner join @Production p
    n p.plant_number = pls.plant_number
 and p.production_date = pls.production_date
 
    WHERE 
 MONTH (p.production_date)= Month (@monthtodate)
 and pls.actual_volume <> 0`

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: I am. This same query is also in my main query for the dataset. But in this case the UDF is getting data for the prior month end and inserting it into a dataset that is set up to return MTD. So I was TOLD that this was the best way to do it. I tried to mimic a prior UDF as best I could.

Comment: I did. Whether or not it's right is a different story. Currently I get NULL. I know that the query works by itself so I'm not sure why I'm getting NULL. And my boss said this would be EASY. Sure, if I had more than 3 months of SQL under my belt. And basic SQL at that.

Comment: SO you get null when you run the udf code by itself in a select like above>

Comment: @HGLEM yes. But I could also be setting it up wrong. Since this is stuff they DON'T teach in school, at least at mine, I'm googling everything when I don't have access to one of our other sql guys. And that's pretty often right now. I THINK I set this test up right:
    `
declare @date1 datetime
declare @date2 datetime

set @date1 = '09-01-2011'
set @date2 = '09-30-2011'

Select
plant_code,
actual_volume,
dbo.PriMonthAvgPrice(@date1,@date2, pls.plant_code) AS 'PriMoAvgPrice'

from
woodproduction.dbo.plywood_layup_sales pls

where
production_date between @date1 and @date2`

AVGPRICE retns NULL

Comment: And sorry everyone for my adding code in my comments. I thought I was doing it right by wrapping it with `code`

Comment: @HGLEM and I ran it like you suggested and I get NULL as well

Comment: @HGLEM here are the some of the results (159 rows returned):
    `211996.48000 862.55359 Elgin Plywood
     105351.42000 430.35466 Elgin Plywood
     35859.04000 141.40000 Elgin Plywood
     244734.39000 963.09580 Elgin Plywood`

Comment: @HGLEM question. Is it possible to use the DATEADD to get the last day of the prior month along with my selected report parameter within an expression in SSRS instead of using a UDF?